# Available Input scopes for textbox windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

What are the Available Input scopes for textbox in windows phone 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full list of InputScopes that are expected to be supported, based on the current enum names for InputScopeNameValue:

```
   AddressCity

   AddressCountryName

   AddressCountryShortName

   AddressStateOrProvince

   AddressStreet

   AlphanumericFullWidth

   AlphanumericHalfWidth

   ApplicationEnd

   Bopomofo

   Chat

   CurrencyAmount

   CurrencyAmountAndSymbol

   CurrencyChinese

   Date

   DateDay

   DateDayName

   DateMonth

   DateMonthName

   DateYear

   Default

   Digits

   EmailNameOrAddress

   EmailSmtpAddress

   EmailUserName

   EnumString

   FileName

   FullFilePath

   Hanja

   Hiragana

   KatakanaFullWidth

   KatakanaHalfWidth

   LogOnName

   Maps

   NameOrPhoneNumber

   Number

   NumberFullWidth

   OneChar

   Password

   PersonalFullName

   PersonalGivenName

   PersonalMiddleName

   PersonalNamePrefix

   PersonalNameSuffix

   PersonalSurname

   PhraseList

   PostalAddress

   PostalCode

   Private

   RegularExpression

   Search

   Srgs

   TelephoneAreaCode

   TelephoneCountryCode

   TelephoneLocalNumber

   TelephoneNumber

   Text

   Time

   TimeHour

   TimeMinorSec

   Url

   Xml

   Yomi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get details from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue(v=vs.105).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh393998(v=vs.105).aspx

Few examples are Digits, Password, TelephoneNumber.